# how to convert selectitem in combobox with datarow value

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-express

I got error when I run my program that user choose item form combo box (from database) then program display a row that connect with value in list box

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\;DataBase=StudentDB;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillCom();
    }

   
    public void fillCom()
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student", con);
        da.Fill(dt);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
    }
 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create the SqlCommand object
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
        {
            CommandText = "spGetStudentById", //Specify the Stored procedure name
            Connection = con, //Specify the connection object where the stored procedure is going to execute
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure //Specify the command type as Stored Procedure
        };

        //Create an instance of SqlParameter
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Id", //Parameter name defined in stored procedure
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, //Data Type of Parameter
            Value = comboBox1.SelectedText //Value passes to the paramtere

            //Specify the parameter as input
        };
        //Add the parameter to the Parameters property of SqlCommand object
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        //Open the Connection
        con.Open();
        //Execute the command i.e. Executing the Stored Procedure using ExecuteReader method
        //SqlDataReader requires an active and open connection
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //Read the data from the SqlDataReader 
        //Read() method will returns true as long as data is there in the SqlDataReader
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            //Accessing the data using the string key as index
            listBox1.Items.Add(sdr["Id"] + ",  " + sdr["Name"] + ",  " + sdr["Email"] + ",  " + sdr["Mobile"]);
            //Accessing the data using the integer index position as key
            //Console.WriteLine(sdr[0] + ",  " + sdr[1] + ",  " + sdr[2] + ",  " + sdr[3]);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Code Update : I add this event

```
   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
           
                //Create the SqlCommand object
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
                {
                    CommandText = "spGetStudentById", //Specify the Stored procedure name
                    Connection = con, //Specify the connection object where the stored procedure is going to execute
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure //Specify the command type as Stored Procedure
                };
                //Create an instance of SqlParameter
                SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Id", //Parameter name defined in stored procedure
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, //Data Type of Parameter
                    Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue //Value passes to the paramtere

                    //Specify the parameter as input
                };
                //Add the parameter to the Parameters property of SqlCommand object
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
                //Open the Connection
                con.Open();
                //Execute the command i.e. Executing the Stored Procedure using ExecuteReader method
                //SqlDataReader requires an active and open connection
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //Read the data from the SqlDataReader 
                //Read() method will returns true as long as data is there in the SqlDataReader
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    //Accessing the data using the string key as index
                    listBox1.Items.Add(sdr["Id"] + ",  " + sdr["Name"] + ",  " + sdr["Email"] + ",  " + sdr["Mobile"]);
                    //Accessing the data using the integer index position as key
                    
                }
                con.Close();
            }
```

I try to convert the value in combobox1.selectItem, but error message display say cant convert data row to int.

Comment: `Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue`

Comment: @LarsTech oh my god , I've tried everything I know except this TT thank you so much

Comment: It works because you set this property: `comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";`

Comment: @LarsTech yes I see,can I ask you another question

Comment: why when I copy the code inside button click  event  to comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event  desnt work ?

Comment: Debug it.  What's `comboBox1.SelectedValue` returning when you have it running in the SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: System. InvalidCastException
   HRresult=0x80004002
   Message=Failed to convert parameter value from DataRowView to Int32.                     @LarsTech  this error message

Comment: That's not what I asked.  Put `var x = comboBox1.SelectedValue;` at the top of that code block.  What's the value of `x`?

Comment: the value of x is null , because in the beginning nothing is selected in combobox

Comment: you mean I cant use SelectedIndexChanged event because nothing is selected in the first ?

Comment: How's it firing if you're not selecting anything?  Or just short-circuit the routine: `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) return;`

Comment: Note : when I write a code in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event the form not open because the error

Comment: same message error appear

Comment: You are talking about code I can't see.  Try updating your post with the new setup.

Comment: @LarsTech oh sorry ,I update the post